# React Native: accessing notification object information without tapping on the banner

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, notifications

I've just implemented a notification feature on my RN project using RN firebase. I have sorted the parts where user clicks on notification and it triggers something in the app when it opens.
HOWEVER, I'm currently struggling to understand the flow of most apps out there where the case is like this:

- User received and **ignored** the notification
- User then later launch the app manually without tapping on the notification
- Most apps I know, esp Instagram and Whatsapp would be able to still show in-app badges letting user know that they have new items incoming and highlight the newly received items

Now, I have successfully done the in app badges part in case user received the notification while app is in foreground, just like what Instagram and Whatsapp does.
But I just can't figure out how to identify, on app **manual** launch (not tapping on notification banner), if the user have some unopened notifications on the tray except by checking `firebase.notifications().getBadge()`. Problem with this, is that I wouldn't be able to know what do the new unopened notifications contain...

I have a feeling this is not something to be handled by notification module or firebase per se because this part has nothing to do with opening up a notification object on arrival.

Basically, I'm really not sure where to look right now. Any pointers would be highly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a notification is delivered and the user did not open it, you need to store it somewhere and retrieve this data when the user opens the application without opening the notification.

For Android, you can use Shared Prefences and for iOS, you can use NSUserDefaults.

You can store the data as a stringified JSON. So when a user starts the applicatio, you can get the data from here and prepare your application according to these data.

If a user clicks on the notification or launches the app after getting your data, you should clear out this place to avoid data corruption.